# Hide SharePoint page title based on a Permission Group

Tags: sharepoint-online

I know that you can target audiences on web parts and such, but can you hide/show a page title depending on a site's permission group?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't hide the title OOTB. You'd have to add some sort of third party tool, or run some javascript.

You could look into adding a script editor webpart in with code similar to the following:

```
<script language="javascript">
$( function() {
    // Get context for current page, set a permission level to evaluate, and set query to 
    // check if they have these base permissions
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var ob = new SP.BasePermissions();
    ob.set( SP.PermissionKind.manageWeb )
    var per = web.doesUserHavePermissions( ob )

    // Execute Query
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function() { // On Success Query
           var titleField = document.getElementById( "DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" )
            if ( per.get_value() ) {
               titleField.style.display = "inherit"
            } else {
               titleField.style.display = "none"
            }
        },
        function( a, b ) { // On Failed query
        } );
} );
</script>
```

It's a self-executing function that checks for the user's current base permission level (like Edit, Contribute, Full Control, etc) then inside the success function (commented with `// On Success Query`) you put your script to change display. This exact setup works on my publishing page on-prem 2013. To change the permission type, you'll have to select a new Enumeration. You can use [this reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee536458(v=office.15)) to get the different enumeration types. To select your enumeration type, change `SP.PermissionKind.manageWeb` to `SP.PermissionKind.anotherEnumeration`where `anotherEnumeration` is from the reference above.

Comment: Thanks so much for the guidance! This is definitely more guidance than I was expecting so I do appreciate it. Originally, I was planning to go down the JavaScript route, but I was unsure how to target a custom groups permissions so I really do appreciate the guidance!

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents No problem! Good luck. But please note that this doesn't do **custom** permissions. Just **base permissions**. I don't know the best way to get "if User is in (HomePage - Members) group" but it'll still allow you to say "If User has (Contribute) permissions to site" .

Comment: I might be able to set some custom permissions for that particular group and just target that, so it still helps as some guidance. I tried checking dev console to see if there is a div class/etc.. added between hidden content on audience targeting but nothing was showing.